# Programmaticaly simulating Alt + Enter key press is not working

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, console

Here is my code:

```
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0, 0, 0);
Sleep(200);
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

The first line would press <kbd>Alt</kbd>
The second line would press <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> (or <kbd>Return ↵</kbd>),
The fourth line would release <kbd>Alt</kbd>,
The fifth line would release <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> (or <kbd>Return ↵</kbd>).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the [`KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) flag to keep the keys pressed down.  Change your code to:

```
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
Sleep(200);
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Also you really don't need the sleep in the middle if you are just sending a <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can see all of the keycodes here at the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx).

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> = `VK_MENU`
- Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> = `VK_LMENU`
- Right <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> = `VK_RMENU`

Comment: Thanks, but also, do you know where is Left ALT, LMENU doesn't work.

Comment: are you put wrong order code?